# Kafka: listener.name.internal.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm vs ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I searched online but I am not able to understand the difference between this two Kafka properties:

- listener.name.internal.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm
- ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm

Are they the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listener.name.internal.*` properties are only applicable if you have `INTERNAL://` as a `listeners` configuration, and you want to override the default.

Otherwise, all listeners will use `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm`

From docs

> Different security (SSL and SASL) settings can be configured for each listener by adding a normalised prefix (the listener name is lowercased) to the config name. For example, to set a different keystore for the `INTERNAL` listener, a config with name `listener.name.internal.ssl.keystore.location` would be set. If the config for the listener name is not set, the config will fallback to the generic config (i.e. `ssl.keystore.location`)